NextAuth - How to preserve callbackUrl if user fails to login first time
I'm using NextAuth in my Next.JS project and a CredentialsProvider.  Everything working fine except one scenario:

If unauthenticated user accesses a protected route, they are successfully redirected to a login page.
If their first attempt to login is successful, they are then successfully routed to their original intended protected route.  Yay!
If their first attempt to login is unsuccessful, but their second or subsequent attempt is successful, they are not redirected to the original intended protected route. Boo!

I believe the issue is that the original intended protected route is stored in a callbackUrl in the search params (e.g. https://localhost:3000/login?callbackUrl=/protectedRoute).  however, if the login is unsuccessful, this failure is communicated back by NextAuth also by searchParams (e.g. http://localhost:3000/login?error=CredentialsSignin&code=credentials).
How can I preserve the callbackUrl such that the user gets routed to the original intended protected route in the event that their first attempt to login fails?
Simplified code excerpts:
export const { handlers, signIn, auth } = NextAuth({
    ...authConfig,
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            async authorize(credentials) {
              if (allGood) {
                return userData;
              } else {
                return null;
              }
]});


export default function Login() {

  const [callbackUrl, setCallbackUrl] = useState('/protected/dashboard');

useEffect(() => {
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
 
    const error = searchParams.get('error');
    const callbackUrl = document.getElementById('callbackUrl')!;
    if (error) {
      setError('Invalid username or password');
      toast.error('Please check username and password');
    }
    else
    {
      const callbackUrlFromSearchParams = searchParams.get('callbackUrl');
      setCallbackUrl(callbackUrlFromSearchParams);
    }
);
}, []);

  return <form onSubmit={async (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
  await signIn("credentials", { username, password, redirect: true, callbackUrl: callbackUrl});
}

from packages.json:
    "next": "15.0.4",
    "next-auth": "5.0.0-beta.25",


We dropped NextAuth for several reasons, but it might help anyway: we approached this issue by storing the redirect/callback in a session cookie whenever we nagivate to the login/ endpoint.
